# Connect to MongoDB host

Tags: c#, mongodb, mlab

### SOLVED!

I'm trying to connect to my mongodb on mlab host.
So far, I've used my local host:

```
client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
DB = client.GetDatabase("surffingsite");
```

Once I started using the mlab host, I tried:
(Ofcourse I entered the correct "<>" in the code itself)

```
client = new MongoClient("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbpassword>@ds239071.mlab.com:39071/surffingsite");
DB = client.GetDatabase("surffingsite");
```

But I'm having problems with it.. Am I doing it wrong? Did I forgot to do something in addition?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: @blins seems like connection failed. Do I need to do anything in mongo shell first? because I didnt..

Comment: @blins "Authentication failed".. What <dbuser> should I put inside?